# Cursor for chrome doesn't automatically focuses on the address bar for "incognito window"?

Tags: google-chrome, cursor

It works fine in normal mode but doesn't focus on incognito window:
[Chrome no longer focus address bar after opening a new tab](https://superuser.com/questions/790045/chrome-no-longer-focus-address-bar-after-opening-a-new-tab)

current Version 80.0.3987.163 (Official Build) (64-bit) CMD+SHIFT+N leads to new Incognito tab but cursor is not in the address bar. I tried resizing the window out of fullscreen mode and it works fine.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? The cursor goes to location bar in incognito for me for chrome v80.

Comment: current Version 80.0.3987.163 (Official Build) (64-bit)
CMD+SHIFT+N leads to new Incognito tab but cursor is not in the address bar.

I tried resizing the window out of fullscreen mode and it works fine.

Probably I'll start using CMD+L manually everytime as well.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the issue exists only in fullscreen mode?

Comment: yeah, that's correct.